# Define a std::map with a templated Key type based on a function that is received as a parameter

Tags: c++, templates

My goal is to have a function that returns a map which can have a Key type that changes depending on a function that's passed as a parameter to my function.

I have the following templated function (C++11) as the only compileable solution so far:

```
    template <typename Container, typename Function, typename KeyType>
    std::map< KeyType, std::vector<typename Container::value_type> > 
    group_by(Container &container, Function function, KeyType keyHint) { ...
```

Right now this allows me to use the function this way:

```
// the last parameter is just a type hint for the compiler
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m = group_by(vec, func_that_returns_an_int, 1337);
...
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m = group_by(vec, func_that_returns_an_int, -1);

// if we pass a function that returns bool, the map's key will be boolean
// the last parameter passed is just a hint for the compiler
std::map<bool, std::vector<int>> m = group_by(vec, is_even, true);
...
std::map<bool, std::vector<int>> m = group_by(vec, is_even, false);
```

My goal would be to not have to pass a random value to hint the compiler of what the Map's Key type should be, I wish I could do something like this:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m = group_by<int>(vec, func_that_returns_an_int);
...
std::map<bool, std::vector<int>> m = group_by<bool>(vec, is_even);
```

or is this even possible too?

```
std::map<bool, std::vector<int>> m = group_by(vec, is_even);
```

I was playing with, auto and decltype to see if the compiler could be hinted by the left hand side of the operation with no luck.

```
auto group_by(Container &container, Function function) -> std::map< decltype(function(Container::value_type)), >
```

Comment: it would be `decltype(function(std::declval<typename Container::value_type>()))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing order or template parameter would allow you to call it

```
group_by<int>(vec, func_that_returns_an_int);
```

So change

```
template <typename Container, typename Function, typename KeyType>
std::map< KeyType, std::vector<typename Container::value_type> > 
group_by(Container &container, Function function, KeyType keyHint)
```

to

```
template <typename KeyType, typename Container, typename Function>
std::map< KeyType, std::vector<typename Container::value_type> > 
group_by(Container &container, Function function)
```

To remove completely `KeyType`, you have to deduce it from other parameters:

```
template <typename Container, typename Function>
auto group_by(Container &container, Function function)
-> std::map<decltype(function(*container.begin())),
            std::vector<typename Container::value_type> >
```

Comment: Thank you!, thanks to you I've learned how the order of the template parameters matters. You're awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::result_of<>`:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Container, typename Function, typename KeyType = std::result_of_t<Function()>>
auto group_by(Container c, Function f) -> std::map< KeyType, std::vector<typename Container::value_type>>
{
    return // ...
}

int bar() { return 42; }

int main()
{
    auto v = group_by(std::vector<double>{}, bar);
}
```